# What will be the output voltage graph of the following circuit if output voltage is considered across the resister?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, resistors, output, graph

The circuit is given below.

I know that until the Vin reaches the first peak, the voltage across R (output voltage) will be 0 since capacitors draw current to charge.

After that, I couldn't figure it out.

Please help me understand.

[image]

Comment: For Steady state only  or both (transient +steady assuming source applied at t=0  from graph)?

Comment: steady state only.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for steady state analysis, this is essentially a HPF (high pass filter), so it will only allow siganls with frequencies above a certain threshold (cut-off frequency) to be passed through the capacitor (aka the capacitor will act as short circuit).

There is a simple way to see this, which is the equation of the capacitive reactance
[image]

So as the frequency increases, the reactance decreases, aka the "resistance" of the cap decreases, hence it acts as a short circuit.

And there is also a different approach using the frequency domain analysis as well
[image]

Quick calrification, the cut-off frequency is the frequency at which the output power is half of that input power, and sometimes is called teh 3-dB cut-off frequency.

Comment: If someone can tell me how to post equations that would be great, thank you.

Comment: [You can use MathJax.](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5565/most-common-mathjax-uses-in-electrical-engineering)

Comment: Hi abd- you can learn from here , how to write equation -https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you very much indeed JRE & user215805.

Comment: Your opening sentence is very naïve; there is no cut-off point at which signals get through or are rejected.

Answer (score 0):

> until the Vin reaches the first peak, the voltage across R (output voltage) becomes 0 since capacitors draws current to charge

Wrong! Use equation written below and then think how charging and discharging takes place.

Hint- $$I={VSin(\omega t +\phi)/Z}$$ where $$Z^2=R^2+X_c^2$$ and $$Cos \phi=R/Z$$
$$V_R=IR$$